# Independencia en Vista Parcial usada varias veces en la misma View MVC4 asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vistas

Hola tengo una duda ojala puedan ayudarme.

Tengo una vista llamada "index" que tiene una tabla dentro, luego en los cuadros de la tabla invoco varias veces la misma Vista parcia llamada(prev), en "prev" tengo un div principal con id="principal" que tiene que contener una imagen.

El problema es que quiero que cada imagen tenga diferente tamaño y posición dependiendo del tamaño del div "principal" el cual tiene un tamaño definido por el tamaño del cuadro de la tabla donde use "renderpartial(prev)" , cree una función js para hacer esto de cambiar el tamaño y posición de la imagen, pero como ya saben las vistas parciales no tiene independencia de contexto, y, el archivo que lee el navegador, recibe una tabla con todos los cuadros cargados con el mismo div="principal" y la función js que cambia el tamaño y posición de la imagen solo trabaja sobre en primer div="principal" por qe todos los div se llaman igual. Esto no sucedería si cada vista parcial tuviera  su propio contexto. ¿Alguna forma de hacer lo que necesito con independencia entre vistas parciales?

P/D me recomendaron generar dentro de "prev" los IDs del div="principal" en tiempo de ejecución, algo como

```
<div id="principal@ViewData["indiceRecibido"]"....
```

pero no se si seria una buena práctica.

Comment: Los `id`s de HTML, si los utilizas, deberían de ser únicos. El `id` se utiliza para identificar de manera unívoca un elemento dentro del DOM. Si existen varios elementos con el mismo `id` no sirve para nada. Otra cosa es que la solución a tu problema pase por crear `id`s únicos o no. Habría que ver el código de tus vistas y el javascript para ver cual puede ser la mejor alternativa.

Answer (score 0):

gracias por responder.

Asi me quedo:

Index:::

```html
<table style="width:100%;height:100%" border="1">
        <tr name="fila1">
            <!--al setear el ancho de las columnas de la primera fila las otras se adaptan solas-->
            <td colspan="4" style="width:68%;height:400px">
               
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" style="width:32%;height:400px">
                @{ Html.RenderPartial("prev", @Model.ElementAt(1)); }
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr name="fila2">
            <td colspan="3" style="width:50%; height:300px">
                @{ Html.RenderPartial("prev", @Model.ElementAt(2)); }
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" style="width:50%; height:300px">
                @{ Html.RenderPartial("prev", @Model.ElementAt(3)); }
            </td>
        </tr>
```

prev:::

```html
@model FormatiLat.Models.Noticia

<script language="JavaScript">

    $(function () {
        var lolo = $("#" +@Model.Id.ToString());
        //si es horizontal
        if (lolo.width() - lolo.height() > 0) {
            var tamaño = lolo.width() / 2;
            lolo.css("width", tamaño);
        }
    });
</script>

<div  class="p-prev">
    <div id=@Model.Id.ToString() style="width:100%;height:100%">
        <img id="imgprev@Model.Id.ToString()" src="~/Imagenes/@Model.Imagen" style="width:100%;padding:10px" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Pero sigo pensando qe existe alguna forma de hacerlo con las vistas parciales independientes una de otra, de forma que no tenga que generar los ids en tiempo de ejecución, osea que cada "prev" tenga un div y una funcion qe trabajen juntos y sean independientes, que no se interfieran los ids.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es marcar todos los elementos para poder seleccionar por ejemplo con una clase:

```
@model FormatiLat.Models.Noticia

<div  class="p-prev">
  <div class="imagenPrev" style="width:100%;height:100%">
    <img id="imgprev@Model.Id.ToString()" src="~/Imagenes/@Model.Imagen" style="width:100%;padding:10px" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Y el javascript lo pones en la vista principal para que se recorra todos los elementos y los redimensione:

```js
$(function () {
    var prevs = $('.imagenPrev').each(function(i, prev){
      var lolo = $(prev);
      //si es horizontal
      if (lolo.width() - lolo.height() > 0) {
          var tamaño = lolo.width() / 2;
          lolo.css("width", tamaño);
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%;height:100%" border="1">
      <tr name="fila1">
          <!--al setear el ancho de las columnas de la primera fila las otras se adaptan solas-->
          <td colspan="4" style="width:68%;height:400px">

          </td>
          <td colspan="2" style="width:32%;height:400px">
            <div  class="p-prev">
              <div class="imagenPrev" style="width:100%;height:100%">
                <img src="~/Imagenes/@Model.Imagen" style="width:100%;padding:10px" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr name="fila2">
          <td colspan="3" style="width:50%; height:300px">
            <div  class="p-prev">
              <div class="imagenPrev" style="width:100%;height:100%">
                <img src="~/Imagenes/@Model.Imagen" style="width:100%;padding:10px" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td colspan="3" style="width:50%; height:300px">
            <div  class="p-prev">
              <div class="imagenPrev" style="width:100%;height:100%">
                <img src="~/Imagenes/@Model.Imagen" style="width:100%;padding:10px" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Ah listo muchas gracias. No  vi los cambios en el codigo jeje

Comment: No porque jQuery selecciona todos los elementos que tengan la clase imagenPrev y luego se recorren todos con el método each para cambiarlos uno a uno

Comment: Si perdon, recien vi los cambios en el codigo XD. Esta genial la solucion.